# Using substring to remove off spaces,number and non alphanumeric characters

Tags: c#, oop

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace Lab5_Assignment_1
{
       class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string a = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
            string b="DEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZABC";

            Console.Write("Enter your string:");
            string text = Console.ReadLine();
            text = text.ToUpper();
            Console.WriteLine("Input Text = " + text);
            Console.Write("output text = ");
        foreach(char i in text)
        {
            int pos=a.IndexOf(i);
            if(i>='A' && i<='Z')
            {
                 Console.Write(b[pos]);

            }
            else
            {
                Console.Write(i);
            }

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

How do i remove non alphanumeric characters from my input text and output like for example i enter hello world! in my string and i want it to appear like HELLOWORLD in input and KHOORZROUG in output using a substring to remove those characters can anyone help me out here?

Comment: remove the `else` part completely. and change  `Console.Write(b[pos]);` into `Console.Write(a[pos]);`

Comment: i want my input and output to both remove the space and non alphanumeric where my input will be HELLOWORLD and output will be KHOORZROUG

Comment: so just completely remove `else` part. remove this `else
            {
                Console.Write(i);
            }`

Comment: my input will still be HELLOWORLD! and output will be KHOORZROUG which is not it.